# Batch file- Find Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Setup in a Folder using Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing, cmd

How do I check in my current folder that:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable setup exists using a batch script ,
```

Since it is an .exe file I guess I need to do something so that I could read the file description.

I can parse through the list of available files those exists in folder as:

```
 for /r %%i in (*) do echo %%i
```

the name of the file is

```
 vcredist_x86_2008
```

Can some one do this for

```
  Microsoft_VC90_CRT_x86
```

which is a .msm file

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
dir *Redistributable*.exe
if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo Error
```

Basically, you issue dir command and then check for status ( i.e. whether dir found something or not ) using ERRORLEVEL. If dir was successful then ERRORLEVEL will have 0 value.

Comment: this is what i get whe i write this code

i am currently in C:\Validation MSI



 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is AB3A-98C5

 Directory of C:\Validation MSI

File Not Found
redistributable found

Comment: do you have that executable in your current directory ? if yes, what is the complete name of that file ?

Comment: but the problem is that on some other system it might have a diff name

Comment: Change the "dir *Redistributable*.exe" to "dir <your file name>". what we are trying to do here is, issue dir command and see if it was successful or not.

Comment: what if i give this batch to u and u change the file nameto ashish.exe i guess there must be something for the type of file

Comment: usually, the file name for that exe remains same, mostly "vcredist_x86.exe". ofcourse, "x86" (platform code) will be changed to something else. But at least you could check for "vcredist"? And, if someone did change it to ashish.exe, then its user's fault, just display the error message.

Comment: If someone gives you executable say "a.exe", you wouldn't be able to tell whether it is some kind of genuine application or a redistributable or a virus.

Comment: and what about the msm file

Comment: check for .msm as well just like you would check for .exe.

Comment: try using: "IF EXIST <filename> <do something>" repeat this for both the filenames